# How to place a variable in a json Request

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I'm a newbie to JavaScript and React Native.  Is there a way to place variables in a json request?  What I mean is, say I'm using Fetch or Axios and I want to make a json request to a URL. In my instance the json request is for a bible verse json file, but the URL requires the last bit to be the specific verse. For example, https://getbible.com/json/John3:16 (fake URL). Because I want to change the actual verse, can I format the request to replace 'John3:16' with a variable so that Fetch grabs the last bit of the url from somewhere else? Like

```
'https://getbible.com/json/' + verse

const verse = 'John3:16'
```

And if so, how would I go about that?

Comment: You need to assign the variable before you concatenate it to the URL.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 1):

Using fetch you can do as such:

```
const fetchVerse = (verse) => 
  fetch(`https://getbible.com/json/${verse}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));

fetchVerse('John3:16');
```

Make sur you use  ` quotes and not '

Hope it helps ;)